# Memory problem using python pandas to join stock DataFrames in loop

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to join a lot of dataframes in order to do the correlation matrix in pandas.
So, it seems that I have to keep on adding columns on the right hand, with the "Date" as the index.
But, when I try to do this function with just 50 dataframes, it ends with the memory error.

Is there anyone knows what is happening?

```
def taking_and_combining_data_from_mysql_to_excel(root):

    saved_path = root + "\main_df.xlsx"

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    for key, value in stock_dic.items():
        mycursor.execute("""SELECT date, Adj_close 
        FROM hk_stock 
        Where date >= '2020-03-13 00:00:00' and stock_number = '{}'""".format(key))

        row_result = mycursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(row_result) 
        df.columns = ['Date', value] 
        df.set_index('Date',inplace=True) 



        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df

        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df,how="outer")



    with pd.ExcelWriter(saved_path) as writer:  

        main_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="raw_data") 
        main_df.corr().to_excel(writer,sheet_name="correlation")  

    return main_df
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas` is not designed for such dynamic concatenations. You could just append things into a list, and convert that list into a DataFrame. Like so:

```
join=[]
for key, value in stock_dic.items():
    join.append({'Date':value} )
df_join=pd.DataFrame(join)
```

Comment: But the problem is "append" adding information on rows.
What I need is to add information on columns to do the correlation...